# Validation issue using jQuery

Tags: jquery, regex

I am trying to validate a time duration user input using jQuery and it keeps returning invalid even though input is valid. Regular expression validates inputs of the form mm:ss or m:ss. I tested in online using [online regex tester](https://regex101.com/) and it is working fine (passes inputs like 07:29 or 7:29).

However, when I use jQuery to validate it it always fails.

This what I have (abbreviated form):

```
function validateUpdateSubmit() {debugger
    var isValid = true;
    ....
    // value of "duration" below is "07:29"
    var duration = $("#tbDuration").val();
    var durationExp = new RegExp("^[0-5]?\d:[0-5]\d$");
    ...
    if (duration == '' || !durationExp.test(duration)) {
        $("#lblErrDuration").show();
        isValid = false;
    }
    return isValid;
}
```

I tried:

```
    var validDuration = (duration == durationExp.exec(duration));
```

But it also returns false when value is "07:29" or "7:29".

Comment: Is the text being validated in exactly 07:29?  I ask because ^ and $ would mean if you had a space like "07:29 " it would not match.

Comment: I checked again and it is exactly "07:29", no space.

Comment: It seems this question was indeed a duplicate of first link listed on top of the page. the problem was that I had to use \\d instead of \d in regex string.